# JSP display tag without column/property name specified

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

Let's say you don't know the column names in this one table but want to display all the columns & values in there.
Is there a way to use display tag without specifing property names?

```
<display:column property="column_name" title="Column Name"/>
```

I usually do this way, but this requires the property name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this [Simplest Case, No columns](http://www.displaytag.org/10/tut_basic.html)?